# Is it possible to compile a Win32 app with clang++?

Tags: c++, winapi, clang

I've got the first step of this simple Microsoft tutorial working in Visual Studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program

But let's say that Visual Studio's licensing terms aren't compatible with my end goal, so I'm trying to make the same thing work with `clang`.

So, naively, I install LLVM and the Windows SDK. Then I try the following:

```
PS ~> & 'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe' `
  -o bin\win32-program.exe `
  -I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt\' `
  -I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\shared\' `
  -I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\' `
  -I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\' `
  -I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\winrt\' `
  -L 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64\' `
  -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt_enclave\x64\" `
  -L 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64\' `
  .\src\win32-program.cpp
```

But the linker can't find any of the external symbols.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassW referenced in function wWinMain
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateWindowExW referenced in function wWinMain
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try linking with (for example) `user32.lib`?

Comment: @PaulSanders I was trying to imitate what VS adds to the environment variables `INCLUDE` and `LIB`. FWIW, the following approach has the same problem: `& 'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe' -o bin\win32-program.exe -I 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\Windows.h' -L 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64\User32.Lib' .\src\win32-program.cpp` (I am, of course, new to clang and C++, so I may be missing something rather obvious.)

Comment: Is it still not finding those specific two symbols?  There are probably other libraries you also need to link against.

Comment: BTW, `-L` specifies a folder to look in for libraries to link against.  To link against a specific library, you want `-l`

Comment: @PaulSanders Thanks... I tried explicitly including all SDK Lib directories for my architecture via a config file. No dice. Then I started running clang in verbose mode and discovered those directories were being added anyway. And still the symbols were missing. I'm more mystified than when I started.

Comment: Can you add the command line you're currently using to invoke clang to your question please?  (It's hard to read as a comment).  Maybe then someone can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Your problems in windows programming will be by far more complex than picking the "correct" compiler just to write a hello world. It will be *too long* in win32 coding before you actually need to consider changing to clang. If you actually are an 'one of those fuddy-duddies who thinks the only thing you should need to program the machine in front of you is a text editor and a compiler' then Windows programming is not for you anyway.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis What you say may well be true. But for me, the accumulating complexities of build systems can be a form of entropy. I've found it helpful to understand the essentials. Then later, I can enjoy all of the hard work that the tools are doing for me. And I'm better able to make sense of the logged output, and separate the signal from the noise.

Comment: @LeoOrientis Windows is not like Linux at all. You don't have *time* to know the internals. You are too busy with many other things.

Comment: The `-L` option adds a directory to the search path for libraries. The `-l` option specifies an actual library name to link with. If the name does not include a full path the directories added by `-L` are used in the search for a library with the matching name.

Comment: *"I'm not happy putting Visual Studio at the centre of everything."* - Right. Instead, just put CMake *"at the centre of everything"*. That won't soothe *your* pain, but at least you're suffering the same as anyone else. That aside, what is your actual question?

Comment: *"Microsoft could write its `cl.exe` compiler with non-standard linking functionality included."* - I'm curious: What's **standard** linking functionality? *"Or is there something fundamental I'm missing about how to tell a C++ compiler to include the necessary Windows SDK libraries?"* - Probably. A compiler doesn't know (or care to know) how to link an executable or library. That's what a linker does. Note that you aren't seeing any compiler errors (`LNKnnnn` are linker errors).

Comment: Just to echo what others are saying here, Visual Studio is a superb IDE (especially the debugger) and there's no reason not to use it.  The Community Edition is even free.  If you want a peek behind the scenes, it will show you the command line it is passing to the compiler and linker.  Put it this way: I (and the other guys here) are professional Windows developers, so if it's good enough for us...

Comment: @PaulSanders I certainly didn't mean to say anything against VisualStudio - which, as you say, is a splendid IDE. And I'm very grateful for the help you and Retired Ninja provided around Clang and C++ compilation in general. Your comments greatly improved my understanding of the relationships between VS, cl.exe, other compilers, C++ libraries, and the Windows SDK. If either of you would like to provide an official answer, then I'd happily accept it. I'm not entirely certain why my wanting to understand these things has ruffled some feathers, but again, I'm most grateful for your help.

Comment: Not ruffled!  More, erm, avuncular :)

Comment: @PaulSanders In all fairness, VS is squarely focused on MSBuild. A build system for .NET, that **barely** manages to compile (and link) C++ code. VS is a superb IDE, for .NET developers. For everyone else, it's ok-ish. Provided that you have half of a minute of your life to spare, waiting for it to launch, and getting its act together. VS regressed with the release of VS.NET in 2002, and never recovered. The only consolation us native developers have is launching VSCode, and take note that VS is better than worst-in-class...

Comment: @IInspectable Ooh, that's a bit harsh.  MS seem to have upped their game wrt C++ development in the last year or two, after focussing on .NET so heavily.  My biggest personal gripe is the flaky nature of Edit 'n Continue, a killer feature that used to work perfectly in VS 2005 and has never been quite right since. YMMV

Comment: @IInspectable But you're right, it is a shade heavyweight

Comment: *"allowed me to understand that you use `-L` to include a directory of libraries"* -- You misunderstand. The `-L` option does not cause any libraries to be linked (what you call "include"). All `-L` does is tell the linker where to look for the libraries that you specify elsewhere (with `-l`).

Comment: Your "question" reads more like a story than a question, especially after the edit. Sometimes stories are amusing, but in this case I found myself asking "Where is the question? Will this get to the point?" Some advice from [ask], with added emphasis: *"The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging **and informative** as possible."*

Comment: @PaulSanders Edit and Continue doesn't work the same because NX bit is now a thing. So recompiling in place is highly problematic now. You can technically make it work somewhat the old way in 32bit code but not 64bit.

Comment: @Mgetz Now this is the frustrating thing.  It works most of the time, than mysteriously stops working until the next full recompile.  Maybe you can explain why.  My app is 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments that I needed to provide to `clang++` to get that simple Win32 demo to work were the following:

```
> "C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang++.exe" `
    -o .\bin\win32-program.exe `
    -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\" `
    -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\" `
    -l "kernel32" `
    -l "user32" `
    -D "_UNICODE" `
    -D "UNICODE" `
    .\src\win32-program.cpp
```

The command-line help for `clang++` is both dense and terse, so here is what I needed to find in it:

- `-I <dir>  Add directory to the end of the list of include search paths` (To locate the Windows header files.)
- `-L <dir>  Add directory to library search path` (To locate the Windows libraries containing the implementations I required.)
- The `-l` argument is required to link with a specific library. You must not include the `.dll` file suffix for some reason. `-l` is not documented in the LLVM command-line help or web page (at time of writing). However, it appears that if I had previously used gcc, this arg would have been very familiar to me. (https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html)
- And, of course: `-D <macro>=<value>  Define <macro> to <value> (or 1 if <value> omitted)`

The credit for this answer should really go to all who provided helpful feedback in the comments, especially Paul Sanders. Thank you!